# How can I make text change color after button click and change back the color after a couple of seconds of no clicking?

Tags: javascript

I want some text to go red when a button is clicked.
The button can be clicked many times and will make the text stay red.
After a bit of not clicking the button, the text should go back to black.

Here is a JSFiddle of what I tried: https://jsfiddle.net/9tdschym/1/

```
<p class="text">Text</p>
<button>Click</button>

.clicked {
  color: red;
}

let text = document.querySelector( '.text' )
let btn = document.querySelector( 'button' )

btn.onclick = () => {
    text.classList.add( 'clicked' )
  setTimeout(() => {
    text.classList.remove( 'clicked' )
  }, 500)
}
```

I can't use a setTimeout because then there would be many setTimeout calls in the stack thus messing up what I am trying to achieve.

I know I can probably hardcode a solution by using a variable to check if it has been clicked along with some other checks to check when it was last clicked but I think there is a better solution out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changed to toggle and added a bit more time. Seems to work now.

Added a flag to prevent multi clicks.

```js
// Text will change for (n) milliseconds on click. 
// Further clicks will reset timeout 
let text = document.querySelector( '.text' )
let btn = document.querySelector( 'button' )
let timer = undefined;

btn.onclick = () => {   
   if(timer !== undefined) {
      clearTimeout(timer);   
   } else {
    text.classList.toggle( 'clicked' )
    }
  timer = setTimeout(() => {
    text.classList.toggle( 'clicked' );
    timer = undefined;
  }, 1500)
}
```

```css
.clicked {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="text">Text</p>
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: No, I want it to stay red when the button is getting clicked. And after 500ms of the button not being clicked, it goes back to black. I don't want the red to flicker back and forth between red and black which is what your code is doing.

Comment: Added the `clicked` bool to deal with rage clicking. Increase the `1500` to whatever you need time wise.

Comment: Ok, give me a moment. So every click resets ?

Comment: Hmm... that is a better solution.

Comment: Hmm.. with your solution, there are still a bunch of setTimeouts firing in the callstack  so not all clicks would equate to 500ms of red. If you click the button and then wait 499ms and click again, the text would go back to black because the setTimeout would fire.

Comment: Ok, let me change.

Answer (score 0):

It actually works but you need to enter 5000 because this works in milliseconds

Comment: I dont think so because then there would be a bunch of setTimeouts firing in a row 5 seconds later if you click the button many times. Also, I set it to change back in 500ms on purpose. I dont want 5s

Answer (score 0):

This might do it for you. A simple adjustment by checking if its active or not

```js
let text = document.querySelector( '.text' )
let btn = document.querySelector( 'button' )
let active = false


btn.onclick = () => {
 if(!active){
  text.classList.add( 'clicked' )
  active = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
     text.classList.remove( 'clicked' )
     active = false;
  }, 1500)
 }
}
```

```css
.clicked {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="text">Text</p>
<button>Click</button>
```